# Is there any reason to not generate page hashes for authenticode signing with signtool.exe?

Tags: .net, dll, code-signing, signtool, authenticode

According to [this TechNet article on forced integrity checking](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/255.forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx#Use_the_ph_option_with_SignTool), there are some circumstances where generating page hashes (the `/ph` option) is required. There are other circumstances mentioned where pages hashes are recommended for performance reasons.

Given that generating page hashes is optional, it seems logical to conclude that there must be some possible negative consequence for generating page hashes. However, neither the TechNet article nor the [`signtool.exe` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) the documentation provides no reasons given for why one would choose not to generate page hashes.

Are there any possible negative consequences that can come from generating page hashes for Authenticode signing?

Comment: You assume there must be negative consequences but in a lot of cases, if there's no *benefit* to you doing X unless you need it for Y, there won't be a lot of documentation about why you wouldn't do X.

Comment: It is optional because not every machine can use /ph.  Clearly stated in the requirements, the machine that does the signing must boot Vista or higher.  Odd restriction btw.